# Reactjs + MaterialUI: RaisedButton is broken

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

#### Problem description

Hi,

I have an error with use RaisedButton and FlatButton.

What is the cause?

[image]

code:

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '20px'}}>
          <RaisedButton
            label="Button"
            primary={true}
            style={{margin: '12px'}}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
```

error:

> react-dom.min.js:15 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #119; visit
>   http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=119
>   for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full
>   errors and additional helpful warnings.(…) ReactTransitionGroup.js:110
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentWillLeave' of
>   undefined(…)

#### Versions

- material-ui@0.16.4
- react@15.4.1
- react-dom@15.4.1
- react-tap-event-plugin@2.0.1
- Browser: Chrome 54

Comment: Do you have any errors with **non** minified React?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5109#issuecomment-244055551

Comment: Thank you for your help!